# Пропадают все записи с JTable.

Tags: jtable

До этого такой проблемы не возникало, совсем не пойму, что делать. Изначально у таблицы есть только заголовки, но после добавления записи остаётся только пустая таблица.

Код:

> ```
> public NewJFrame() {
>         initComponents();
>
>         DefaultTableModel d = new DefaultTableModel();
>         d.addRow(new Object[] {1, 2});
>         jTable1.setModel(d);
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
DefaultTableModel d = new DefaultTableModel(0 /*rowCount*/, 2 /*columnCount*/);
```

Ну или

```
DefaultTableModel d = new DefaultTableModel();
d.addColumn("First row head");  
d.addColumn("Second row head");
```

Comment: А что именно этот код делает? Точнее, что за параметры в скобках?

Comment: @Сергей1991: там же даже комментарии есть :) количество строк и столбцов.

Comment: @Сергей1991: вот должно быть полезным: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html

Comment: Ну у меня уже есть заголовки, зачем добавлять их повторно?

Comment: @Сергей1991: ну так не добавляйте, если не надо. ;-) В вашем коде я их не увидел, поэтому и написал. Пользуйтесь первым вариантом, если заголовки есть.